# InvalidOperationException when closing a WindowEx window in WinUI 3

Tags: c#, window, persistence, unhandled-exception, winui-3

Recently, I created a new *WinUI 3* (v1.2) desktop app using *Template Studio for WinUI*. Because starting unpackaged apps in `Debug` is so much faster than packaged apps, I chose an unpackaged app in the setup wizard. The resulting barebones code created an app that always crashed when closed using the `Close` method or the `Close` button on the `System Menu`.

The app throws an unhandled exception which `VS 2022` catches in **App.g.i.cs** in the following section:

```c#
#if DEBUG && !DISABLE_XAML_GENERATED_BREAK_ON_UNHANDLED_EXCEPTION
    UnhandledException += (sender, e) =>
    {
        if (global::System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached) global::System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();
    };
#endif
```

You can disable this by setting the `DISABLE_XAML_GENERATED_BREAK_ON_UNHANDLED_EXCEPTION` variable in the project `Properties` (under *Build -> Conditional compilation symbols*) but the program will still throw the error (this code simply gives you a convenient way to trap unexpected errors).

Can anyone explain why this is happening with an unmodified new project and how to correct it, please?

Comment: Is there any question here? If you have a question and already an answer, please 1) post a question, and 2) answer it.

Comment: Sorry. Edited question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The template code generates a `MainWindow` that is of the class `WindowEx`. This nifty extension of the `Window` class adds quite a few helpful features (see: [WinUIEx Wiki](https://dotmorten.github.io/WinUIEx/)) but some of them aren't completely documented yet. The `WindowEx` class creates a `WinUIEx.WindowManager` to manage the `WindowEx` window. When the `WindowEx` is closed, `WinUIEx.WindowManager.Window_Closed()` is called which then calls `WinUIEx.WindowManager.SavePersistence()` which is the cause of the crash mentioned above.

`SavePersistence()` tries to save some of the window characteristics so they can be restored when the app restarts. However, the persistence services are only enabled for **packaged apps**, not unpackaged (which I used). To turn this behavior off, set the `PersistenceId` property of the `WinUIEx.WindowManager` instance to either `null`, `string.Empty`, or `""` (the template sets `PersistenceId = "MainWindow"` by default). Just add

```c#
    var manager = WinUIEx.WindowManager.Get(MainWindow);
    manager.PersistenceId = string.Empty;
```

somewhere after `MainWindow` has been instantiated (I put it in `App.OnLaunched`). I hope this helps.